# strtok() tokenizes only once when nested

Tags: c, string, strtok

Suppose I have the following string: `0:1,2,3`.

I want to separate first using `:` as the delimiter and when it gets to the second part (i.e `1,2,3`) and try to use `strtok` on that (with `,`) it does not work as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){
    char s[10];
    strcpy(s, "0:1,2,3");
    char* token1 = strtok(s, ":");
    //To let me know it is on the second part
    bool isSecondToken = false;
    while (token1) {
        printf("token1: %s\n", token1);
        if(isSecondToken == true){
            char* token2 = strtok(token1, ",");
            while (token2) {
                printf("token2: %s\n", token2);
                token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
        }
        token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        isSecondToken = true;
    }
}
```

Output I get:

```
token1: 0
token1: 1,2,3
token2: 1
token2: 2,3
```

Expected output:

```
token1: 0
token1: 1,2,3
token2: 1
token2: 2
token2: 3
```

Comment: Your call to strtok inside the loop says you want to split by space, not comma, so it'll return until next space is found which is never, hence "2,3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When updating the `token1` and `token2` pointers you need to use the same token splitter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char s[10];
    strcpy(s, "0:1,2,3");
    char* token1 = strtok(s, ":");
    //To let me know it is on the second part
    bool isSecondToken = false;
    while (token1) {
        printf("token1: %s\n", token1);
        if(isSecondToken == true){
            char* token2 = strtok(token1, ",");
            while (token2) {
                printf("token2: %s\n", token2);
                token2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
        }
        token1 = strtok(NULL, ":");
        isSecondToken = true;
    }
}
```

Also `strcpy` requires the `string.h` library, so you were probably also getting some warnings of implicit declaration.